# Items that SHOULD be showing in a view, aren't

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, filter, indexed-column

So, I have a large list, with ~10,000 items.
I have created several views that filter via indexed columns that show below the threshold amount.

But I just modified one of the views, (changed the displayed columns) and now when I search for a term, 1 or 2 items are displayed, when I know for a fact that there are many that the filter shouldn't be filtering out, that never used to filter out before the change (which shouldn't make any difference).

If I look through the list manually, I can find items that the search should have included.

I'm currently trying a reindexing, I'm not sure how long this is supposed to take, but it is a fairly large site.

I've noticed this peculiar behaviour before - any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It indeed seems that reindexing did the trick. Just had to wait a little while.

- On the site, click Settings > Site Settings.
- Under Search, click Search and offline availability.
- In the Reindex site section, click Reindex site.
- A warning appears, click Reindex site again to confirm. The content will be re-indexed 
  during the next scheduled crawl.